# quick release pipe clamp

Tags: rims

I want to secure my inline electric mash heater to my brew bench but be able to quickly break it down for cleaning purposes.  I'm thinking the easiest way to do this would be some type of quick-release clamp or clamps that can handle 180 degree wort.

It's basically a 1" copper tube with a water heater element in it, fed by a 1/2" NPT "T" near the base of the element, and a 1/2" NPT reducer at the far end of the tube.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?  I don't really know what to Google for.

Comment: Working on this writeup, I will post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used a 1" setup, nor have I seen one, but hey lets see if this will work for you.

The easiest way will be to buy 2 of [these clamps](https://www.brewershardware.com/Mounting-Bracket-for-1.5-RIMS-Tube.html).

They have a 10mm threaded port on the bottom that can be bolted or welded to your stand. They have quick releases to easily remove your RIMS tube and clean it.

If you would like to mount it vertically that will take a little bit of moding your tube, but the clamps would still be the best.

You would just need to sweat on a 2 of [these slip couplings](http://www.lowes.com/pd_59664-137-CL600_4294822005__?productId=3506710&Ns=p_product_avg_rating%7C1) where they will match up with your mounts.

You can do this for the horizontal mount as well for extra security.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is a pretty cool setup... of course it cost about 10 times as much as mine...

Comment: Well ya, that RIMS tube is costly. However I was saying you could just buy the quick release clamps, and use the slip couplings to make your RIMS tube fit better into the 1.5" clamps.